# No endpoint listening error in new web site in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I just downloaded Visual Studio Community 2015

I am trying to create a new web site using VB.net.  When I create a new web site (not a project) and use the web forms template, the application generates a site for me with all the standard pages, resources, etc.  The issue is every page that gets created has the first line of every .aspx page highlighted with an error.  This is the line that was generated in the Default.aspx page:

`<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>`

And the error that I get when I hover over the line says this:

```
    "C:\Users\jonat\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Websites\Website1\Default.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: There is no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/f0934344-a63a-4324-ba7c-62644c40c01/CBMOutOfProcService that could accept this message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

I have no idea what this error message is trying to tell me.  All I did was try to create a new web site.  I did not change any code in any page or any file that was generated by Visual Studio and yet I get this error.

Any ideas?
Thank you,
Jonathan

I have the following from Visual Studios About:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA487 Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA487 Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA487 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.1.00719.1 Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11107.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.8 Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.8.35.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

Open VS 2015 as Administrator.

Just seen the [answer](https://forums.asp.net/t/2100375.aspx?No%20endpoint%20listening%20error%20)
 now.